# Eclipse does not overwrite file at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using a pre-existing project with the eclipse IDE. I import the files and set it up. However when I go to run my project none of the changes I made to any of the java files are saved/overwritten.  I'm not sure if it's some setting deep in eclipse that allows the overwriting of imported files. I'm using a glass fish server if that is relevant at all. Thanks for the help! If I can provide any other details please ask!

Comment: How have you imported your project to Eclipse ?

Comment: Yes. I used the import existing projects option and selected copy files to the workspace.

Comment: If you've copied project to workspace, your changes are made to that copy (in your workspace folder). Typically, you want to import the project in place.

Comment: Even when I don't select the option to copy to workspace I get the issue.

Comment: After you make changes, are you publishing the app to your server?

Comment: Yes. I build the project with the glass fish server.